# CakePHP not sure if it's the right thing

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this controller: Resales, and I am in the Administrator controller and need to create a new Resale.. how should I do that?

first option:
Administrator form calls /resales/addResales

second option: Administrator has a method addResale that loads the Resale model and inserts it.

What should I do?
thanks

Comment: If I'm reading your question right, I'm going with option 1, assuming by "Administrator form" you mean the form view itself. It's more descriptive and restful. Also, controllers shouldn't be working with other controllers, they should be agnostic to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Administrator` controller shouldn't be loading the `Resales` **controller** - that should be a model that both controllers use. You should load your `Resales` model into the `Administrator` controller in the `$uses = array()` property at the top of your controller file:

```
class AdministratorController extends AppController {
    var $uses = array('Resale', //the rest of your models);

    public function createResale() {
        $this->Resale->create();
        $this->Resale->set($this->data['Resale']);
        $this->Resale->save();
    }

}
```

Other options are that you could use Ajax to post the request for you, or you could use `$this->requestAction()` in your Administrator controller to use a processing function in your Resales controller:

```
// administrator controller
public function createResale() {
    // define your data here
    $result = $this->requestAction('resales/create', array($data_array));
}
```

Have a look at the manual for more information on `requestAction`:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html

> EDIT

You've just asked about views. In this case, there's no real need to create a view for `createResale()`, what you might want to do instead is set a [Session flash message](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#creating-notification-messages), then redirect back to your form. You will need to ensure you've included the Session helper at the top of your controller:

```
class AdministratorController extends AppController {
    var $helpers = array('Session', // any others here);
```

Then you prevent the layout and render of views, do your thing and set a session flash with the results message:

```
public function createResale() {
    // don't render a view or layout
    $this->layout = '';
    $this->render(false);

    // process your request
    $result = // do stuff... return true or false for result

    $msg = $result ? 'Added successfully!' : 'Error adding resale!';
    // set flash message
    $this->Session->setFlash($msg);
    // return to that form
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'formYouCameFrom'));
}
```

Now on your form, you'll simply do this:

```
echo $this->Session->flash();
```

... which will output the results.

Comment: and about my Administrator Form Action be like /resales/create?

Comment: It would be `/administrator/createResale` - you could post to your `resales` form, but then you have to deal with redirection back out of it in multiple situations.

Comment: Ok, and my Administrator controller needs to have a View, right? so I created a method that will display the view with the form.. then I created another method for the post.. am I right?

Comment: You got me wrong, I guess.. 'Cause I have this /administrators/formForCreateANewResale.. then I need formForCreateANewResale ACTION in ADMINISTRATORS controller.. isn't that?

Comment: Correct, action for your form and a view that renders your form. You may as well use the same action as above and use `if(isset($this->data))` to determine whether to process the form's data or just display the form. Might be time to read a CakePHP tutorial.

Comment: Ok, I got that all! thanks buddy.. I already read that, but I still having some doubts..